# From a table to an html page using an ajax script

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Good afternoon,

Basically, I am trying to adapt the great script from Eliza Witkowska available at http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii and I'm struggling, hence my post today on stackoverflow.

In my html file, I have 3 checkboxes (chk1, chk2 and chk3). What I would like is to retrieve their value from the mysql table 'tbl_prototype' by linking its technical_name_html and update the 3 checkboxes as follows :

```
a) if the value is *100* -> check the tickbox
b) if the value is *0* -> uncheck the tickbox
```

I am trying to use the ajax query which works to do that but I am not quite sure where to start.

Do you have any suggestion for me, so I could go forward with this nice project?

I am available for any question.

Many thanks for your kind help and have a great day.
Laurent

> Contents of my file 'index.html'

```
<?php require('common.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo for Ajax Auto Refresh</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_day.css" />
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.news);
            }
        });
    }
    //Every 1/2 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,500);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a demo for post <a href="http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii">Ajax Auto Refresh - Volume II</a></h1>
<?php /* Our message container. data-counter should contain initial value of couner from database */ ?>
<div id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="chk1"> Living room<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="chk2"> Entrance<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="chk3"> Kitchen<br>
</body>
</html>
```

> Script to generate the table and some data in the mySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_prototype` (
  `id_component` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `technical_name_html` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `component_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  INSERT INTO `tbl_prototype` (`id_component`, `technical_name_html`, `component_name`, `description`, `value`) VALUES
  (1, 'chk1', 'light_living_room', 'The light of the living room', 0),
  (2, 'chk2', 'light_entrance', 'The light of the entrance', 100),
  (3, 'chk3', 'light_kitchen', 'The light of the kitchen', 0);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_prototype`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_component`);
ALTER TABLE `tbl_prototype`
MODIFY `id_component` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

> Contents of my PHP file 'checker.php' :

```
<?php require('common.php');
//get current counter
$data['current'] = (int)$db->check_changes();
//set initial value of update to false
$data['update'] = false;
//check if it's ajax call with POST containing current (for user) counter;
//and check if that counter is diffrent from the one in database
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['counter']) && (int)$_POST['counter']!    =$data['current']){
//the counters are diffrent so get new message list
$data['news'] = '<h1>OMG! It\'s alive!!! NEW UPDATE !!!</h1>';
$data['news'] .= $db->get_news();
$data['update'] = true;
}
//just echo as JSON
echo json_encode($data);

/* End of file checker.php */
```

> Contents of my PHP file 'common.php' :

```
<?php
require_once ('db.php'); //get our database class
$db = new db();
/* end of file common.php */
```

> Contents of my PHP file 'db.php' :

```
<?php
/**
 * Class db for Ajax Auto Refresh - Volume II - demo
 *
 * @author Eliza Witkowska <kokers@codebusters.pl>
 * @link http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii
 */
class db{

/**
 * db
 *
 * @var $   public $db;
 */
public $db;


/**
 * __construct
 *
 * @return void
 */
function __construct(){
    $this->db_connect('192.168.0.XY',user','1234','database');
}


/**
 * db_connect
 *
 * Connect with database
 *
 * @param mixed $host
 * @param mixed $user
 * @param mixed $pass
 * @param mixed $database
 * @return void
 */
function db_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database){
    $this->db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

    if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
    }
}


/**
 * check_changes
 *
 * Get counter value from database
 *
 * @return void
 */
function check_changes(){
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM news WHERE id=1');
    if($result = $result->fetch_object()){
        return $result->counting;
    }
    return 0;
}


/**
 * register_changes
 *
 * Increase value of counter in database. Should be called everytime when
 * something change (add,edit or delete)
 *
 * @return void
 */
function register_changes(){
    $this->db->query('UPDATE news SET counting = counting + 1 WHERE id=1');
}


/**
 * get_news
 *
 * Get list of news
 *
 * @return void
 */
function get_news(){
    //if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<>1 ORDER BY add_date DESC LIMIT 50')){
    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_prototype')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $return .= '<p>id: '.$r->id_component.' | '.htmlspecialchars($r->description).' | '. $r->value . ' | ' .  $r->technical_name_html . '</p>';
            $return .= '<hr/>';
        }
        return $return;
    }
}


/**
 * add_news
 *
 * Add new message
 *
 * @param mixed $title
 * @return void
 */
function add_news($title){
    $title = $this->db->real_escape_string($title);
    if($this->db->query('INSERT into news (title) VALUES ("'.$title.'")')){
        $this->register_changes();
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
}
/* End of file db.php */
```

Comment: Is the basic script working so far?  Are you getting any errors?  The basic concept seems simple enough:  1. Use AJAX to find if new changes were made.  2. If so, echo those changes in a JSON format and update the counter.  It sounds like you need help with 3. Decoding the JSON data and using jQuery to update your checkboxes based on the data in the JSON response.

Comment: The basic script, as published, is working. Unfortunately it only displays some data and doesnot the checkbox as I would like.

Comment: Then you need to change 2 things:  1. Change checker.php to look up the data you really want from your table and echo it.  2. Change index.php to get the response from checker.php and use javascript to update your checkboxes accordingly.

Comment: Look here for help on PHP, AJAX and mySQL: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp  Look here for help with the javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: Sorry if the question may sound silly, but how do I link the response from checker.php with the check boxes? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the links I posted above for help completing the steps I mentioned above.  No offense, but without understanding the code, nothing I can tell you will help short of me writing all the code for you.  The links I posted will hopefully teach you what you need to know to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

at the first glance, what I can see is the jquery code has to be written within the document ready function something like below.

/* AJAX request to checker */

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.news);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very much appreciated. Do you think I need to do something special somewhere to update my check boxes?

Comment: The AJAX code doesn't HAVE to be in the document ready function, but putting it there ensures the page is loaded before the AJAX call is made.  In this case, it's made every 500 milliseconds by the line `setInterval(check,500);`.  Removing this line removes the entire functionality of the script Laurent's trying to adapt.

Comment: Additionally, you'll see this script works as it is written, but Laurent hasn't adapted it to do what he wants yet.